# outlier in Nested ANOVA in Gage R&R

Tags: anova, nested-data, msa

is there any specific method to identify outliers and reduce their impact in ANOVA on Nested design because I have Nested design on Gage R&R which contains 4 outliers in 3 operators .

Answer (score 1):

As long as the "outliers" are actual measurements, you need their impact on the ANOVA to help describe the repeatability and reproducability of the gage.  Eliminating unfavorable measurements would be the same as stating, "Except for when we measure things wrong, our measurement system is fool-proof."